# Handling links from template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

currently I'm handling links this way:

```
<a ng-click="goToLink('/foo')">foo</a>

$scope.goToLink = function(url) {
    $location.path(url)
}
```

because if I do

```
<a ng-href="/foo">foo</a>
```

the page is of course reloaded(and getting 404), because it should be something like:

```
<a ng-href="#/foo">foo</a>
```

Is there a directive or something to define links that are 'html5 mode agnostic', so that I don't have to put the hashtag in every link?

Something like

```
<a ng-smart-href="/foo">foo</a>.
```

Answer (score 5):

Check ng-href, It is exactly what you are looking for.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

Check "Relative links" example from [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: When I try <a ng-href="/foo">foo</a> I get a full page reload. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @sammla, Have you checked the example of $location?

Comment: Yes, and I see its working there, but I can't figure out what configuration I am missing. I tried adding a base href with no luck. And the example says "Here you can see two $location instances, both in Html5 mode" and in the script I see $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); (I am using hashbang mode), but in the example it uses hashbang. It's kind of confusing.. :S

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 mode, will rewrite `<a href="/foo">link to foo</a>` to hash-bang mode if in a legacy browser:

See the documentation on this: [Using $location, Html link rewriting](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#htmllinkrewriting).